How to get Jupyter Notebook to use the latest version of Python I have installed?
I saw another variant of this question here on Stack Overflow, but the first answer started talking about the glories of virtual environments and all I could think was "Could we please start walking before we start running?". I'm sure virtual environments are all kinds of wonderful and I'm a pitiful wretch for not using them, but at first glance they strike me as overkill for what I actually want to do.
The problem for me started when a Jupyter Notebook cell decided to barf on a "match" statement, printing just "syntax error" with no other clue. Strange to me, because I'd successfully used "match" many times before in my Python progams.
Eventually it occurred to me to wonder if there was some kind of Python version problem. Yes, as it turns out the Python version I use for most programming is "3.11.x" but Jupyter Notebook is still using "3.7.x". Well, that explains why it doesn't like "match".
I could re-write the offending section as a chain of "if" statements, or I could try to persuade Jupyter Notebook to use a more recent version of Python. That seemed to be a better long term solution, so I wanted to try that.
According to many sources, the idea is to use a magical "pip" incantation. The ever-helpful AI now appearing in my browser suggested
pip install --update "jupyter notebook"

I tried that because I didn't want to spend a lot of time searching. But pip didn't like that very much and gave me an error message. I really couldn't it read very well because it came out as red text on a black background. Not enough contrast there for my taste (actually, "pip" first wanted me to update "pip" itself, again in hard to read green and red text).
Geeks for Geeks suggested that invoking
pip install --update jupyter

after installing a new version of Python would get Jupyter Notebook to actually use it. Well, that certainly caused pip to go into a whole lot of downloading and installing, but in the end Jupyter Notebook still says it's using Python 3.7.x.
I suppose I could delete Jupyter Notebook entirely and try to re-install it from scratch. But that might be overkill. Is there perhaps something less drastic I could try?

I recommend you limit yourself to an actual question instead of some opinion piece on StackOverflow and other random unrelated stuff.

A good start would be to tell us what your setup is and how you're using this Jupyter notebook. Is there a reason you don't upgrade to Jupyterlab, as is the official recommendation?

Question needs help should have been vetted better. On phone sorry.

The question I want answered is what I wrote in the title of the post. That seemed straightforward enough. But I anticipated responses along the lines of "have your looked to see if this question has been answered before?" and "what else have you tried so far?", so I

...tried to answer those in the body of the post.
My setup doesn't seem to me to be anything special. It's just Windows 10 with a copy of Anaconda I installed a few years ago. I did that only because of an online course I was taking at the time and thought Jupyter Notebook was the most interesting thing about it.
I've never heard of Jupyterlab. I don't follow what you might mean by "how you're using this notebook". Does what I want to do with it affect the answer to my question in any way?

There's lots on properly connecting Anaconda/conda to a version of Python. Such as top two answers here. But...." a copy of Anaconda I installed a few years ago". Both Jupyter, and as a result Anaoconda, have change dramatically in the last few years. If you want to pick up using them and have current things work, it is best to just uninstall (cleanly!) and reinstall the Anaconda Distribution. Alternatively if you don't need Anaconda/conda's project and environment management, at this point...

 you may want to install and use JupyterLab Desktop. It has a different model about project management though and so please read that blog post if you do go that route. "I've never heard of Jupyterlab." JupyterLab was to be the new version of Jupyter going forward. Turns out it still is. Because lot of people still prefer the document-centric Jupyter Notebook style interface and so there is an option. The interface for newer Jupyter Notebook 7+ is built on JupyterLab components.

I see. Thank you, I will take a look.
